# Find function in dll source code

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I have C++ source code of some library, which I recently built. According to DLL Export Viewer, this library only contains one exported function, called CreateInterface. The problem is I can't find it in source code, there is no such function. Also, searching dllexport gives 0 results. How is it even possible?

Comment: You linked a static library that provides it.

Comment: Is there a .def file? It can be used to export functions without using __declspec(dllexport)..

Comment: bmargulies was right